# Relative path in 'file' protocol for URL

Tags: java, spring, file, url

I have an implementation which reads a file and uses `java.net.URL` to take a path to open connection to.

In production code, the link of file will be on FTP but for testing the logic I want to use a file locally which I can read using `file` protocol instead of `ftp`.

I am using Spring and changed the file path to something like below-
**application-test.properties**

```
#file location 
enzyme.dat.ftp.link=file:///Users/username/project/src/test-integration/resources/input.dat
```

As you can see its a absolute path, which I need to make relative to my project. How can I do it?

I just need something like below-

```
#file location 
    enzyme.dat.ftp.link=file://${project.basedir}/src/test-integration/resources/input.dat
```

Comment: Whosoever downvoted, consider giving a comment about what is not clear in the question! Many thanks for your view :)

Answer (score 2):

`new URL("file:relative/path/to/file.txt")`

The path is calculated starting from the current working dir of the application.

This answers the exact question, but actually, the recommendation to read the resource from classpath is better unless the file is really external to the project.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you want to read is on the classpath then you could use something like the following:

```
new ClassPathResource("input.dat").getURL();
```

when trying to read the properties file, that way you can simply reference the file name ("input.dat") in your test properties. If the file is not on the classpath then you'll have to use a different mechanism.

Comment: The file path is being injected in my service with @Value. I cannot use ClassPathResource then, I think. That is why I switched to `file`

Comment: There's nothing stopping you injecting a filename (with no path) using @Value and then using a `ClassPathResource` to read it. You can also get the  path from the `ClassPathResource` after you've created it if you need it for some reason, i.e. `new ClassPathResource("input.dat").getURL().getPath()`

Comment: You could also create a String to File Spring Converter class to automatically inject a File using your @Value annotation if you wish, instead of injecting the String and doing it non-configuration code.